# Scrollto after hashed link

Tags: javascript, jquery

My site has a fixed navbar which causes problems when using hashes (www.somesite.com/a_page#some_hash) to jump to certain elements on the page. When the page jumps to the hashed element,fixed navbar covers part of the element. I am trying to make it so the page scrolls to element with an offset:

```
function getHash() {
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    return hash; 
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    if (getHash()) {
        $(getHash()).fadeOut(300).fadeIn(300)
            .fadeOut(300).fadeIn(300)
            .fadeOut(300).fadeIn(300);
        scrollTo( 0, $(getHash()).offset().top + 200);
    }
})
```

Now, this the `scrollTo` part is not firing for some reason. The part right above that does (the fadeOut & fadeIn part). When I use the scrollTo line, `scrollTo( 0, $(getHash()).offset().top - 200);`, in the console, it work just as it should. Why isn't it scrolling when I load the page with a hash in the link? Any and all input is appreciated.

Comment: Does `$('html,body').animate({'scrollTop' : $(getHash()).offset().top + 20 } , 400);` work ?

Answer (score 0):

How about a function that overrides the default functionality of any link who's href value begins with a hash tag?  Is that something you'd be interested in?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(e) {
        // prevent the default behavior so your named anchors don't cause
        // a parent with an overflow to 'slide-under' it's parent.
        e.preventDefault();  
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).position().top }, 'slow');
    });
});​
```

[Fiddle proof of concept](http://jsfiddle.net/HKNk6/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Hashes seemed to be causes an immense problem. Especially because a hashed link that refers to the current page does not reload the page. As a result, any new content it not loaded. I just decided to get rid of hashes and use query parameters to simplify all the issues associated with hashes.

My url's now look like this:

```
www.some_site.com/some_page?element=3434
```

Then this query to find the element and scroll to it with an offset:

```
function getUrlVars() {
    var vars = {};
    var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) {
        vars[key] = value;
    });
    return vars;
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    var post_url_param = getUrlVars()["element"];
    var hashed_element_id = '#' + post_url_param;
    if (post_url_param) { 
            $(hashed_post_id).fadeOut(300).fadeIn(300).fadeOut(300).fadeIn(300).fadeOut(300).fadeIn(300);
            scrollTo( 0, $(hashed_post_id).offset().top - 250);         
    }
})
```